# C# ReportViewer Control Alternative

Tags: c#, report

Good day,

I would like to know if anyone can suggest an alternative to Visual Studio's built in report Viewer control.

The simple reason being that we work with large amounts of data and the built in report Viewer can't hanndle the load (to be more specific we use reports which relies on close to 30 000 records). SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) is not an option since we use both Oracle and SQL Server Databases depending on the environment. We did implement a "batch run" solution to our current system where we only handle an x amount of records at a time but this solution doesn't work with the large amount of records we now use.

For more info we currently rely on rdlc files for your individual reports and based on which report needs to be generated the Database query is constructed and executed and the report viewer is then used to show the results. (The real problem is the ReportViewer Control it simply can't handle the sheer amount of data).

The alternative can be a free or pay to use solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure someone is interested in having a printout of 30.000 records?

Comment: Perhaps there is an average, totaling, or min/max being done on some data. 30,000 records doesn't necessarily mean more than a one page report!

Comment: @alzaimar yes our clients are

Comment: @Steve no there is multiple pages each page makes use of about 54 records (or 180 if printed duplex)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Fast Report. I've worked with the VCL solution for years and if the .NET version is anything close, it's worth a try. You can download a trial version from their website afaik.